# How do I boot the RPi into a python GUI instead of Raspbian desktop?

Tags: raspbian, python, xorg, gui

I've been trying to get the RPi to boot into a custom python script that constructs a simple GUI using pygame, but nothing I attempt has any success.

What are the steps I need to follow to get this working?

Also, if I run `startx python start.py` -- I get the following error:

```
FATAL: Module g2d_23 not found.
xinit: Unable to run program "/usr/bin/xterm": No such file or directory
```

The reason I need it to work this way is because I'm showing a video feed and some other processing in the window that a user can only view and not really break out of (that's the plan).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Non-GUI script

If I want to start any non GUI script, I prefer putting it in `rc.local` as by the time `rc.local` gets executed, everything is up by then (network, mysql and any other services like apache etc).

To do that,

1. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
2. Add your command before `exit 0` line : 
   like `python /path/to/script.py >> /dev/null 2>&1 &` where path should be absolute path.

Notes on this method :

1. All the things in the rc.local would be executed as a root user by default.
2. All the paths in your program should be absolute. It takes home path as `/home/pi`.
3. `>> /dev/null 2&>1` discards any output on stdout. For more info, why it is used, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21).

### GUI script

To execute anything that uses GUI, (x11), you will have to add that to LXDE autostart file.

Here is how to add,

1. `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
2. You should be able to see 3 lines in raspbian by default.
3. You can add a line at the end to execute your script.
   for example , `@sudo python /path/to/script.py`.

Notes on this method :

1. autostart method doesn't execute script / program as a `root` user by default.
2. You might need to add `sudo` if your program needs it.
3. If you want to execute without showing desktop part, comment the first 3 lines by putting `#` in front of every line and add another line after that `@openbox` which loads open box instead of LXDE.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I had to add `@sudo python /path/to/script.py` to get the actual script working, but your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @SeanNieuwoudt My bad, it was a typo. Let me correct it. :)

Comment: would you perhaps know how to fill the background of the black area once booted with a background image? Currently, only the Python created GUI shows in a small portion of the visible window and that's how it should be, but would be great to just have a background visible?

Comment: @SeanNieuwoudt I usually have full screen GUI screens and didn't actually looked into it but it shouldn't be very difficult. Google around.